# Regex Everything Including Whitespace

Tags: php, regex, web-scraping

I need a regular expression pattern all characters including whitespace what is not a variable in PHP.

```
<li class="xyz" data-name="abc">
    <span id="XXX">some words</span>
    <div data-attribute="values">
        <a class="klm" href="http://example.com/blabla">somethings</a>
    </div>
    <div class="xyz sub" data-name="abc-sub"><a href="http://www.example.com/blabla/images"><img src="/images/any_image.jpg" class="qqwwee"></a></div>
</li><!--repeating li tags-->
```

I wrote a pattern;

```
preg_match_all('#<li((?s).*?)<div((?s).*?)href="((?s).*?)"((?s).*?)</li>#', $subject, $matches);
```

This works well but I don't want to get four variables. I just want to get

```
http://example.com/blabla
```

And anyone can tell me why this does not work like that?

```
preg_match_all('#<li[[?s].*?]<div[[?s].*?]href="((?s).*?)"[[?s].*?]</li>#', $subject, $matches);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `(?:)` will allow grouping but make those groups not captured, for example, the following:

```
#<li(?:(?s).*?)<div(?:(?s).*?)href="((?s).*?)"(?:(?s).*?)</li>#
```

Will output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '<li class="xyz" data-name="abc">
    <span id="XXX">some words</span>
    <div data-attribute="values">
        <a class="klm" href="http://example.com/blabla">somethings</a>
    </div>
    <div class="xyz sub" data-name="abc-sub"><a href="http://www.example.com/blabla/images"><img src="/images/any_image.jpg" class="qqwwee"></a></div>
</li>',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'http://example.com/blabla',
  ),
)
```

All of your matches will be contained in `$matches[1]`, so iterate through that.

Answer (score 0):

## [Don't use RegExps to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1060350)

Read this famous answer on StackOverflow.

HTML is not a regular language, so it cannot be reliably processed with a RegExp. Instead, use a proper (and robust) HTML parser.

Also note that data mining (analysis) != [web-scraping](/questions/tagged/web-scraping) (data collection).

If you don't want a regexp group to store the "captured" data, use a non-capturing flag.

```
(?:some-complex-regexp-here)
```

In your case, the following may work:

```
(?s)<li.*?<div.*?href="([^"]*?)".*?</li>
```

But seriously, don't use regexps for this; regexps are fragile. Use an [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) like `/li//div//a//@href` instead.